BSON expo web configuration, await is not defined
I'm using bson package from npm in my react native expo app and it's working but when I try to use the app as web using expo web with metro bundler, I get this error Uncaught ReferenceError: await is not defined
As I understand it could be because of this:
Technical Note about React Native module import

The "exports" definition in our package.json will result in BSON's CommonJS bundle being imported in a React Native project instead of the ES module bundle. Importing the CommonJS bundle is necessary because BSON's ES module bundle of BSON uses top-level await, which is not supported syntax in React Native's runtime hermes.Technical Note about React Native module import

How can I configure my expo app to go around this or use the right version of it?
